# What's the best way to implement an "undo" feature in photo editing application?

Tags: java, undo, undo-redo

Obviously it takes a lot of memory to store an array of a history of changes... that's how I had my application working but it just seems like there's a smarter way to go about doing this.

```
ArrayList<Photo> photoHistory = new ArrayList<>();
photoHistory.add(originalPhoto);
photoHistory.add(change1);
photoHistory.add(change2);

// bad implementation - lots of memory
```

Maybe store only an original and a current view model and keep a log of the methods/filters used? Then when a user hits 'undo' it would take the total number of changes made and run through all of them again minus one? This also seems incredibly inefficient.

I guess I'm just looking for advice on how to implement a general 'undo' function of a software application.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Calculate delta between after and before change, i.e. delta to apply to new version to reverse the change. History is those deltas. For full filter, that likely is full picture, but for something like red-eye filter, it's only the eyes, i.e. much smaller.

Comment: Well, the command pattern linked by @AndyTurner is a fine pattern generally to follow if you just want to have a generic undo feature. However, what makes it quite complex in the graphic app scenario, is the undo method itself (which needs to be added to every command). Implementing undo in command might not be so easy. As you mentioned - you can keep a list of executed command and re-apply previous ones when you undo the last command. Still, this might be quite inefficient. So, to sum it up - in general scenario Command pattern is ok, but might not be the best option in a graphical editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a tip from how GIMP implements it:

> GIMP's implementation of Undo is rather sophisticated. Many operations require very little Undo memory (e.g., changing visibility of a layer), so you can perform long sequences of them before they drop out of the Undo History. Some operations, such as changing layer visibility, are compressed, so that doing them several times in a row produces only a single point in the Undo History. However, there are other operations that may consume a lot of undo memory. Most filters are implemented by plug-ins, so the GIMP core has no efficient way of knowing what changed. As such, there is no way to implement Undo except by memorizing the entire contents of the affected layer before and after the operation. You might only be able to perform a few such operations before they drop out of the Undo History.

[Source](http://mediaintro.teeks99.com/Photos/Photos-3-Gimp.html)

So to do it as optimally as possible, you have to do different things depending on what action is being undone.  Showing or hiding a layer can be represented in a neglible amount of space, but filtering the whole image might necessitate storing another copy of the whole image.  However, if you only filter part of the image (or draw in a small section of the image) perhaps you only need to store that piece of the image.